# Cronjob with password protected site (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, cron, wget, password-protection, cron-task

I want to create a cronjob that every X time goes to open a webpage.

This webpage is password protected by .htaccess (user=admin, passwor=pass). The instruction I give is the following:

```
wget --user=admin --password='pass' http://www.mywebsite.com/test.php
```

But cron gives me the following error:

```
--2012-05-02 10:14:01--  http://www.mywebsite.com/test.php
Resolving www.mywebsite.com... IP
Connecting to www.mywebsite.com|IP|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Authorization Required
Reusing existing connection to www.mywebsite.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2012-05-02 10:14:01 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

I have also tried doing:

```
wget admin:pass@http://www.mywebsite.com/test.php
```

but with similar errors. How can I solve? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It looks like the wrong password or username is reaching the server. Can you run the `wget` command successfully from a shell prompt, i.e. without using cron?

Comment: Anders, I receive the same error also using shell prompt. But the password is correct, because through the browser it works.

Comment: Then your password must contain some special character that has to be encoded or escaped properly - Does it contain something like `$`, `\ `, `!`, `"` ...?

Comment: no, the password is very simple, composed by only letters

Comment: Then it is a good time to take a sniffer and compare the http traffic in the browser and from wget. The `Authorization:` header should be the same in both cases. Notice that there might be other things that cause this problem, for example restrictions on ip or useragent...

Comment: What kind of authorization do you use? Basic, Digest, or something else? Could you post the htaccess?

Comment: Hi, my VPS provider given me the solution to use -U firefox: `wget -U firefox --user=admin --password='pass' http://www.mywebsite.com/test.php` and now it works

Comment: @Gerben here is my .htaccess: `AuthName "Area Protetta"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
AuthUserFile "/xxx/.htpasswds"`

Comment: The solution using -U firefox above works if you remove quotes from the password.

Answer (score 2):

wget --user admin --password pass http://www.mywebsite.com/test.php

Opens every minutes a website with a htaccess password

```
*/1 * * * *  wget -O /dev/null --user admin --password pass "http://www.mywebsite.com/test.php" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making a small mistake.

keep the **http://** before the url.

You have

> admin:pass@http://www.mywebsite.com/test.php

Change it to

> http://admin:pass@www.mywebsite.com/test.php

Hope that works.

Answer (score 0):

Add auth parameter to url. This works for me when call url directly.

```
http://yoururl.ext?auth=id:psw
```

I don't know how much secure it is...