# Block users from accessing cron job script

Tags: php, cron

I have a PHP script that runs every hour (cron job) to clean up/delete views in a temp views table in my database.

Currently, the URL is:

`http://example.com/api/clean.php`

However, this is accessible by any user, so the script can run due to someone accessing the link and it's easy to guess.

If I made the URL some random string:

`http://example.com/api/090b235e9eb8f197f2dd927937222c5703.php`

would anyone be able to "discover" it to run the script? Is there a better way to block people from accessing the script?

Comment: Why a web-server is involved in this process at all? About complicated URLs, yes - it is not secured. If you have to use a web-server, make it so at least, that your php script will be expecting a $_POST parameter or handshaking.

Comment: @Axalix what do you mean?

Comment: Can you call this script from a console: `php /web/my-site/application/api/clean.php`?

Comment: Put script  in directory outside Web root

Answer (score 1):

Most databases have functions to do this type of thing. In mySQL you can set an event

```
DELIMITER $$

-- SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON$$     -- required for event to execute but not create    

CREATE  /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/ EVENT `dbName`.`eventName`

ON SCHEDULE
     /* uncomment the example below you want to use */

    -- scheduleexample 1: run once

       --  AT 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM.SS'/CURRENT_TIMESTAMP { + INTERVAL 1 [HOUR|MONTH|WEEK|DAY|MINUTE|...] }

    -- scheduleexample 2: run at intervals forever after creation

       -- EVERY 1 [HOUR|MONTH|WEEK|DAY|MINUTE|...]

    -- scheduleexample 3: specified start time, end time and interval for execution
       /*EVERY 1  [HOUR|MONTH|WEEK|DAY|MINUTE|...]

       STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP/'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM.SS' { + INTERVAL 1[HOUR|MONTH|WEEK|DAY|MINUTE|...] }

       ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP/'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM.SS' { + INTERVAL 1 [HOUR|MONTH|WEEK|DAY|MINUTE|...] } */

/*[ON COMPLETION [NOT] PRESERVE]
[ENABLE | DISABLE]
[COMMENT 'comment']*/

DO
    BEGIN
        (sql_statements)
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a `PHP` application hosted externally. The solution was to password protect the folder containing all administrative scripts (including cron job related scripts), so no public access for folder content.

My solution was for Linux and involved configuration [through .htaccess file](http://www.wikihow.com/Configure-Your-Website-Using-Htaccess-in-Linux-with-Apache):

```
AuthName "Admin" 
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/conf/httpd/htpasswd/...
Require valid-user
```

The password file and `.htaccess` file are automatically generated by the hosting company through their panel, but I can access and change .htaccess file.

Bypassing directory password protection is tackled [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410140/cronjob-with-password-protected-site-htaccess):

```
http://user:pass@example.com/api/clean.php
```